# Ruby syntax: can x('foo', y: 'bar', z: 'baz') differ from x('foo', @yz)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

Given a method:

```
def x(*a)
```

Can calling it like so:

```
 x('foo', y: 'bar', z: 'baz')
```

Ever differ from:

```
@yz = { y: 'bar', z: 'baz' }
x('foo', @yz)
```

I'm asking because I've found the I18n.translate method, defined as:

```
def translate(*args)
  options  = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop : {}
  key      = args.shift
  backend  = config.backend
  locale   = options.delete(:locale) || config.locale
  handling = options.delete(:throw) && :throw || options.delete(:raise) && :raise # TODO deprecate :raise

  raise I18n::ArgumentError if key.is_a?(String) && key.empty?

  result = catch(:exception) do
    if key.is_a?(Array)
      key.map { |k| backend.translate(locale, k, options) }
    else
      backend.translate(locale, key, options)
    end
  end
  result.is_a?(MissingTranslation) ? handle_exception(handling, result, locale, key, options) : result
end
```

...behaves differently when called using the different approaches above. When passing in a variable instead of the inline hash, then `locale` is always set to `config.locale` and the built-in locale fallbacks mechanism is prevented from running (regardless of whether `:locale` is present in the hash variable.) Yet, in IRB tests, I can't find a way for `#x` to tell the difference.

I've worked around this for the moment by copy-pasting the hash contents into each #translate call in the app affected, but sure would by nice to know what's up here.

Comment: We probably need to see the code in order to be able to guess what the problem might be. You are right: There should be no difference between `foo(bar, baz: quux)` and `foo(bar, { baz: quux })`. And certainly no difference between the latter and `x = { baz: quux }; foo(bar, x)`.

Comment: yup, same here.. I looked at the source code of the I18n module, and both inputs should work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, they are identical:

```
def x(*a)
  puts a.inspect
end

x('foo', y: 'bar', z: 'baz')
 => ["foo", {:y=>"bar", :z=>"baz"}]

@yz = { y: 'bar', z: 'baz' }

x('foo', @yz)
 => ["foo", {:y=>"bar", :z=>"baz"}]
```

Please note that the syntax you're using will only work in Ruby 1.9 , not in 1.8

Comment: Yeah, I get that, and have tried every which way in IRB to coax a visual difference, but they can't be *totally* identical since the translate method above reacts quite differently to the two "styles" of input.

Comment: can you elaborate why you think the results would be different?
I checked the code of the translate() method, and it does a call to backend.translate(locale, foo, {:y=>"bar", :z=>"baz"})
in both cases!

Comment: It does call through and almost perfectly work with the backend's translate. The trick is that when given a reference to a Hash instead of the inline syntax, the fallbacks mechanism, i.e., foo-bar-baz foo-bar foo, doesn't work. But, I think you've got to be right and the side-effects morass in I18n is just getting itself completely wrapped around the axle, something like @pst's point.

Comment: yes.. that I18n translate() code looks bad.. I'm wondering why they don't just pass _everything_ in as a hash and just access the hash-keys directly .. no argument parsing necessary...

Answer (score 4):

Is a *new* object assigned to the variable *before each invocation of the method*? I suspect not and that the error observed is not due to *how* it's called, but rather *what* it does to the objects passed.

That is, **the `translate` method can cause/causes side effects to the input as it modifies an object passed in**. In this case `options.delete(...)` will create a side-effect that could lead to unexpected behavior in *subsequent* invocations: while the "variable is the same" the object refered to by the variable has been silently ruined. The fix (and "correct" code) is to remove such side-effects.

Happy coding.

Comment: +1 :) ... I'd still like to see an example from Yuri where we can see the problems he's encountering

Comment: This is a very good point, my suspicion is that internally the I18n code is using that passed in hash in such a way that reusing it later is no longer possible (I don't yet see where,) anything else is going to require a belief in mysticism. :)

Comment: +1 for a great and helpful point. I added #dup to the Hash before handing it to I18n each time and the symptom is now gone, thanks again! (Accepted to @Tilo as he nailed my question, regardless of my problem.)

Comment: that I18n translate() code looks bad.. I'm wondering why they don't just pass everything in as a hash and just access the hash-keys directly .. no argument parsing necessary...